# Getting the shortest path with networkx, but pass additional stops the path should go through

Tags: python, networkx, polygon, graph-theory

I am searching for a way to not only pass an orgi and dest to the shortest pass function of [networkx](https://networkx.org) but also some additional edges/nodes where the pass should go through.

My goal is it to use [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) to generate a route that will consider additional stops.

so far I am using the shortest path function to pass a start and a destination. However I would also like to add a list of edges that should be used while going from start to destination.

```
shortest_path(G, orig_edge, dest_edge, 'length')
```

Do you guys have any idea how to easily do that?

Comment: You should call shortest_path several times, for src to first waypoint, fist waypoint to second ... last waypoint to destination

Comment: hmm... yeah sure that would be an option, however I was wondering if there might be an more efficient way I just have missed. Will do it this way however in the meantime. Thanks for your input :)

Comment: Unless the invocation of a method is absurdly expensive in python, then there will no more efficient way of doing this.  If you are so very concerned with efficiency, you should be using a compiled language.  C++, for example, is about 50 times faster than python.

Comment: The snag is that you need to order the waypoints so that the total path length is minimized ( I assume ).  You need a heuristic to guess the correct order of waypoints.  If the the vertices are located in Euclidean space, then the order is straightforward.  Otherwise, I suggest find the length of the shortest path from the source to each waypoint, and order them by increasing distance.  If the number of waypoints is small, you can find the absolute optimum by trying all possible orderings.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72190299/7321942